# "double free or corruption" of shared_ptr in binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, smart-pointers

I'm writing codes about binary tree using smart pointer, but there is something wrong with destructor. I don't know where the momery leaks. But when I remove all components with `parent` pointer in `BinNode`, it runs with no errors.

Header file is showed as follow:

```
#ifndef BINARY_H
#define BINARY_H

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef RANK_DEFINED
#define RANK_DEFINED
typedef int64_t Rank;
#endif

template <typename T> class BinaryTree;
typedef enum {RB_RED, RB_BLACK} RBColor;

template <typename T>
class BinNode {
public:
    friend class BinaryTree<T>;
    BinNode() = default;
    BinNode(const T& data, std::shared_ptr<BinNode> pare = nullptr, std::shared_ptr<BinNode> left = nullptr, std::shared_ptr<BinNode> right = nullptr,
        int h = 1) : _data(data), left_child(left), right_child(right), parent(pare), height(h){}
    ~BinNode() = default;

    std::shared_ptr<BinNode> insertAsLeft(const T& e) {
        left_child = std::make_shared<BinNode>(e);
        left_child->parent = std::shared_ptr<BinNode>(this);
        return left_child;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<BinNode> insertAsRight(const T& e) {
        right_child = std::make_shared<BinNode>(e, this);
        return right_child;
    }
    int size() const;

    std::shared_ptr<BinNode> succ();
    template <typename VST> void travelLevel(VST (*f)());
    template <typename VST> void travelPre(VST (*f)());
    template <typename VST> void travelIn(VST&);
    template <typename VST> void travelPost(VST&);

    bool operator<(BinNode const& bn) { return _data < bn._data; }
    bool operator==(BinNode const& bn) { return _data == bn._data; }

    bool isRoot() { return !(parent); }
    bool isLChild() { return !isRoot() && this == parent->left_child; }
    bool isRChild() { return !isRoot() && this == parent->right_child; }
    bool hasParent() { return !isRoot(); }
    bool hasLChild() { return !left_child; }
    bool hasRChild() { return !right_child; }
    bool hasChild() { return hasLChild() || hasRChild(); }
    bool hasBothChild() { return hasLChild() && hasRChild(); }
    bool isLeaf() { return !hasChild(); }

    std::shared_ptr<BinNode> sibling() const {
        return (isLChild() ? parent->right_child : parent->left_child);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<BinNode> uncle() const {
        return parent->sibling();
    }
private:
    T _data;
    std::shared_ptr<BinNode<T>> left_child = nullptr;
    std::shared_ptr<BinNode<T>> right_child = nullptr;
    std::shared_ptr<BinNode<T>> parent = nullptr;
    int height = 1;
};


// Binary Tree Defination
template <typename T>
class BinaryTree
{
    using BN = BinNode<T>;
public:
    BinaryTree(): _size(0), _root(nullptr) {}
    ~BinaryTree() = default;

    int size() const { return _size; }
    bool empty() const { return !_root; }
    std::shared_ptr<BN> root() const { return _root; }
    std::shared_ptr<BN> insertAsRoot(const T& e);
    std::shared_ptr<BN> insertAsLC(std::shared_ptr<BN> pare, const T& e);
    std::shared_ptr<BN> insertAsRC(std::shared_ptr<BN> pare, const T& e);
    std::shared_ptr<BN> insertAsLC(std::shared_ptr<BN> pare, BinaryTree<T> bt);
    std::shared_ptr<BN> insertAsRC(std::shared_ptr<BN> pare, BinaryTree<T> bt);

    int remove(std::shared_ptr<BN>);
    BinaryTree* secede(std::shared_ptr<BN>);

    template <typename VST>
    void travelLevel(VST& visit) { if (_root) _root->travelLevel(visit); }
    template <typename VST>
    void travelPre(VST& visit) { if (_root) _root->travelPre(visit); }
    template <typename VST>
    void travelIn(VST& visit) { if (_root) _root->travelIn(visit); }
    template <typename VST>
    void travelPost(VST& visit) { if (_root) _root->travelPost(visit); }

protected:
    Rank _size;
    std::shared_ptr<BN> _root;
    virtual int updateHeight(std::shared_ptr<BN>);
    void updateHeightAbove(std::shared_ptr<BN>);
    void delTree(std::shared_ptr<BN>);
};

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<BinNode<T>> BinaryTree<T>::insertAsRoot(const T& e)
{
    _root = std::make_shared<BN>(e);
    _size = 1;
    return _root;
}

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<BinNode<T>> BinaryTree<T>::insertAsLC(std::shared_ptr<BN> pare, const T& e)
{
    auto newNode = pare->insertAsLeft(e);
    _size++;
    updateHeightAbove(newNode);
    return pare->left_child;
}

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<BinNode<T>> BinaryTree<T>::insertAsRC(std::shared_ptr<BN> pare, const T& e)
{
}

template <typename T>
void BinaryTree<T>::updateHeightAbove(std::shared_ptr<BN> x)
{
    while(x)
    {
        updateHeight(x);
        x = x->parent;
    }
}

template <typename T>
int BinaryTree<T>::updateHeight(std::shared_ptr<BN> x)
{
    Rank lh = 1, rh = 1;
    if (x->left_child)
        lh = x->left_child->height;
    if (x->right_child)
        rh = x->right_child->height;
    x->height = (lh > rh) ? lh : rh;
    return x->height;
}

#endif
```

and main function is:

```
int main()
{
    BinaryTree<int> bt;
    bt.insertAsRoot(1);
    bt.insertAsLC(bt.root(), 2);
    cout << bt.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result is `double free or corruption (out)`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with your `parent` links:

- Both the downwards and the upwards pointers are `std::shared_ptr`. This is known as a reference cycle and prohibits your tree from ever being destroyed properly. A common solution is to make the `parent` pointer a `std::weak_ptr`, such that it does not count towards keeping the parent alive.
- The second problem is hidden in your `insertAsLeft`: `std::shared_ptr<BinNode>(this)` will construct a **new** `shared_ptr` with refcount 1. This means that you have multiple `shared_ptr`s pointing to the same block of memory and the first one that drops to refcount 0 frees the block, leaving you with dangling pointers. Luckily for you, C++ has a ready-made solution. Simply inherit from [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) and use `left_child->parent = shared_from_this();` instead. In a nutshell, this construction allows `BinNode` to keep track of which `shared_ptr` owns it.

Comment: Thank you very much, `std::enable_shared_from_this` is very helpful.

Comment: Also it is more safe to have a private constructor for a class that inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this` and use a factory function

Comment: @Botje Are you sure it's advisable to recommend `std::enable_shared_from_this`  in this context?

Comment: If OP wants to construct a tree using `shared_ptr`, why not?

Comment: @Botje Are `new` and `delete` better than smart pointer in tree structure?

Comment: @ketsai that is a long essay by itself. On one hand, you could argue that keeping a reference count is silly, because there will always be exactly one "owning" pointer to a node (the parent). But on the other hand you could argue that this design helps tremendously if you want to safely hand out parts of the tree to others or if you wanted to construct a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) instead of a tree.